# How can we read .docx file using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, office-interop, docx

I want to read a docx File in c#.
the docx file when converted to .zip generate the xml of our file.
I want to read that xml file .
I need all the data from the doc with ther font name (bold italic setting), color from the file.
How can we do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The format of DOCX is well documented.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats#WordprocessingML_.28WML.29) To read the packages, you can use the classes from the [`System.IO.Packaging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Perhaps a better link for DOCX format documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266220.aspx

Comment: Thanks Cody Gray. The link I posted leads to the download of the ISO/IEC 29500-1 PDF which is the authoritative resource as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

Low level answer: DOCX files are OPC (Open Packaging Conventions) format (zip files with a manifest) and can be opened with the classes available in the [`System.IO.Packaging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) namespace.

High level answer: [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) is an opensource framework that supports manipulating DOCX files using higher level constructs.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to read the file as XML then may be you could apply some XPATH queries to get the info you need.